# ActionScript 3 Regular Expression with semicolon in it

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, split

I need to split a string based on `&` and `&amp;` but I'm having an issue, I think because of the ;

To make matters more difficult there is no JavaScript access, so it's becoming quite difficult to debug.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var s:String = "foo=blah&bar=val&amp;name=hi";
var re:RegExp = /(&amp;|&)/g;
var ar:Array = s.split(re);
```

But I'm not seeing the correct results. Like I said, no JS so it's hard to tell what's working and what's not (no log files either, btw- all trial and error).

Is it interpreting a statement end because of amp; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with no parentheses:

```
var re:RegExp = /&amp;|&/g;
```

In `split()`' [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) we have the explanation:

> If the delimiter parameter is a regular expression containing grouping
>   parentheses, then each time the delimiter is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the grouping parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array.